# Translate an api results

Tags: json, localization

I'm really wondering if I could translate an api results
let's say for example if I use Food api that display JSON results in English
I want the results to be in Spanish or another language .
is there any tool to help me

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in the past with pretty good results

https://www.npmjs.com/package/translate-json-object

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this library.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sheet_localization_generator

This one is easy to translate any language that google provides. And also control is easy(like excel sheet).